# Replace address with getElementById.href

Tags: javascript, php, href

I have this js code to fetch an address.

```
document.getElementById('st_ip'+dev).href=jsonstring['localip'];
```

I would like you to change with another address
That's how I call it:

```
echo "<a href='' id='st_ip".$row['id']."'>TEST</a>";
```

And it works but not as I would like.

But it makes an append on the main site. I wish it would go to that address instead.

Example:
`www.mysite.com` became `www.mysite.com/www.newsite.com`

How do I tell him to replace the whole address? It's possible?

Comment: `"http://" + jsonstring['localip']`

Comment: Is this some third person language?

Comment: `"http://" + jsonstring['localip']"` I had already tried it and it wasn't gone... Now I tried again and it's gone. Maybe it was cached. Thank you

Comment: Why -1? What is the problem with the request? How can I improve the request?